# Largest audience for a sport match?

Tags: football, media

It was said than one of the last Real Madrid vs Barcelona was watched by 600 millions persons. [Audience Real Madrid vs Barcelona FC](http://www.marca.com/2015/11/20/futbol/madrid-barcelona/1448027329.html)

Is this the largest audience for a sport match or are there F1 or other sport matches which has a larger audience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new record, the 2018 world cup final was viewed by 1.12 billion viewers.

[Record audience world cup](https://www.reuters.com/article/uk-soccer-worldcup-viewers/record-audience-watched-best-world-cup-ever-fifa-idUKKCN1OK19B)

Answer (score 2):

According to FIFA, seems that more than 715 million people watched the 2014 World Cup Final [source](http://www.ibtimes.com/super-bowl-2016-how-many-countries-will-watch-carolina-panthers-vs-denver-broncos-2296360).

So I believe that this events has a large audience than that match